# Error using tensorflow with tf.image.adjust_jpeg_quality , output shape is unknown?

Tags: tensorflow

when I run the demo code:

```
x = tf.random.normal(shape=(256, 256, 3))
y = tf.image.adjust_jpeg_quality(x, 75)
print('y shape is: ', y.shape)
```

output as follows：

y shape is:  (?, ?, ?)

should the output is (256, 256, 3)？ why？  anything wrong？

my tensorflow version is 1.14

Answer (score 0):

In TF 1.x to print output, you need to execute code with in the `session` as below

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x

import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  x = tf.random.normal(shape=(256, 256, 3))
  y = tf.image.adjust_jpeg_quality(x, 75)
  print(sess.run(tf.shape(y)))
```

Output:

```
1.15.2
[256 256 3]
```

In TF 2.x, eager execution enabled by default, hence you don't need `session`

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

x = tf.random.normal(shape=(256, 256, 3))
y = tf.image.adjust_jpeg_quality(x, 75)
print(y.shape)
```

Output:

```
2.2.0
(256, 256, 3)
```